# how to get javascript to send output across multiple divs?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to recreate drug wars and I have no clue if how to get my script to output data to a whichever div it needs to go to. I started writing a script but deleted it so it's not included. Seems like it should be a simple fix tho.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include '/includes/style.php'; ?>
<body>


<div id = "Dbg">
 DrugWars 

</div>

<div id = "layout2">
hry
</div>

<div id = "layout">

</div>

<div id = "layout1">
def
</div>


    #Dbg{
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
text-align:center;
width:1195px;
font-size:50pt;
}

#layout{
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
font-size:30px;
height:598px;
width:580px;
border-color:red;

}

#layout1{
border-style:solid;
border-width:4px;
font-size:30px;
height:290px;
width:580px;

border-color:orange;

}

#layout2{
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;
font-size:30px;
height:900px;
width:610px;
float:right;
border-color:green;
}
```

Comment: I see. The dog ate your homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```
document.getElementById('div's id').appendChild(document.createTextNode("output text"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the appendChild does does but you pointed me in the right direction with the get by id tho, knew it was something simple I should have known by now. I ended up with `<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById("layout");
a.innerHTML = "test";

</script>`

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. Here is an explanation of appendChild if you are interested.

innerHTML is not a W3C standard way of manipulating the DOM, however since it is now cross-browser it is somewhat acceptable.

Remembder the HTML document is organized as a tree. When you call nodeX.appendChild(nodeY); you add nodeY as a child node to nodeX. Append child coupled with document.createElement or document.createTextNode is the spec-conformant way of adding stuff to your DOM.